# How to hide and show the Progressbar in android?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I have written this code to load progressbar and have a button click to make it invisible.
but click listener is not working when I am clicking the button. My app shows ANR.

this is my code:
layout:

```
   <ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2" />

   <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/button_send"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="stop progressbar"
    android:onClick="stopPB" />
```

and java file;

```
public void stopPB(Bundle view) {
    super.onCreate(view);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    ProgressBar PB = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    PB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Remove these line super.onCreate(view);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

Comment: Please search about it ...before asking any questiion...For your question the solution is that...You have to play with View Visibility like, when u are loading any data than show the View by View.Visible And when urs task is completed than u should set the View like View.Gone

Comment: I think your layout doesn't include progressBar2. How did you make it appear?

Comment: @AgiMaulana it's not help.

Comment: @Fox please post the complete layout file and acitivity. Also please post the stacktrace as you say your application crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this :

```
public void stopPB(View view) {
ProgressBar PB = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
PB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```